# EF5 Code First (Error cannot be inferred from the usage)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Ok, I have been pulling out my hair because I simply cannot make a many to many relationship. I have the following two models:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? ChangePassword { get; set; }
    public bool? Deletable { get; set; }

    //Add more Properties for more fields

    public virtual IQueryable<CompanyInformation> ParentCompany { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CompanyInformation
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company Name:")]
    public string companyName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Website Address:")]
    [Url(ErrorMessage="The Website field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or ftp URL. (Example: http://www.website.com)")]
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string contactTitle { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contact First Name:")]
    public string contactFirstName { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    [DisplayName("Contact Last Name:")]
    public string contactLastName { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    [DisplayName("Phone Number:")]
    public string contactPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address Display?")]
    public bool displayAddress { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Phone Number?")]
    public bool displayPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Address 1:")]
    public string address1 { get; set; } 
    [DisplayName("Address 2:")]
    public string address2 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("City:")]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("State:")]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Zip/Postal Code:")]
    public string zipCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Search Engine?")]
    public bool allowSearchEngines { get; set; }


    //Navigation Property
    public virtual IQueryable<UserProfile> CompanyUsers{ get; set; }

}
```

I'm trying to make a many-to-many relationship between these two and I just can't figure out how to do it properly. I should mention that I am very new to the EF Code First.
My Context Class looks like the following:

```
public class myDB : DbContext
{
    public SchedulerDB()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyInformation> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasMany(e => e.ParentCompanies).WithMany(e => e.CompanyUsers);            
    }

}
```

ok, As soon as I add the modelBuilder above I get the following error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Scheduler.Model.UserProfile>.HasMany<TTargetEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Scheduler.Model.UserProfile,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<TTargetEntity>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.  C:\Users\Hiva\Documents\Project\ToDo\Infrastructure\myDB.cs
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find any examples that use the modelBuilder differently to achieve a many-to-many relationship between two tables. Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ICollection for navigation properties:

```
ICollection<UserProfile> CompanyUsers{ get; set; }
```

and

```
ICollection<UserProfile> ParentCompanies{ get; set; }
```

instead of `IQueriable`

Comment: What is the difference? Like I said I'm very new and thought that by using the IQueriable, I can pass linq queries and the system will execute it on the sql server and return only the subset.

Comment: ICollection<UserProfile> is collection of elements with type UserProfile, but IQueriable<UserProfile> can be anything. You can use ICollection and IList for navigation properties. It seems to me that your navigation property collection should have Add method.

Comment: Add Method? I'm sorry, like I said, I'm quite new and am learning as I go along. What do you mean that my navigation property should have an add method?

Comment: Your navigation property is collection of entities (as example Userprofile). EF (inside) take this entities from datareader and should has possibility to add it to collection, so your collection should implement interface with Add method (IList or ICollection).

Comment: oh ok, thank you for the Clarification. Everything is now working flawlessly (well so far :) )